# Referencing to HTML inner tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reference a Html tag within a tag using JavaScript

```
<a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" rel="async-post" ajaxify="12345">
<span class="itemLabel fsm">Delete This Photo</span>
</a>
```

As you can see, the span tag is within the anchor tag but I can only reference to the anchor tag because it has a unique 'ajaxify' value. At the moment I have the variable referencing the anchor tag but I do not know how to reference the span element. I attempted to use `a.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]` but it did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: `a.querySelector('span')`

Comment: As you said if the `a` variable is referring to the correct element then `a.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]` should work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lh2cps5z/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think this would be true, except I receive this error (Uncaught TypeError: x.getElementsByTagName is not a function)

Comment: then `x` is not referring to the anchor elemnet.... how are you getting the `x` variable...

Comment: @ArunPJohny My mistake... I did not use [0] in front of it so it was referencing an array instead. Beginner's mistake! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can also look at querySelector...

Comment: If the problem is solved you can delete the question as it is a typo

Comment: You should avoid using non-standard attributes like `ajaxify`. Use `data-ajaxify` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if JQuery is an option, but here's a resolution

`$('a[ajaxify="12345"] span')`

- `a` references the anchor tag
- `[ajaxify="12345"]` references the attribute with that value

  - Since there is no space it must be an anchor tag with that attribute
- `span` looks for the span inside of the anchor tag with the attribute since it has a space before the span

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tkfde18r/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children` or `childNodes` to get the child node

HTML Code

```
<a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" rel="async-post"  ajaxify="12345" id="parentTag">
<span class="itemLabel fsm">Delete This Photo</span>
</a>
```

JS

```
var elem = document.getElementById('parentTag');
elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(elem.children[0]);
})
```

a demo in this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ahsacgsq/)
Also please take a look at the difference between `children` & `childNode`